# Why do I have superpowers?

Tags: discussion, closing, moderators, dupehammer

I just voted to close a question as a duplicate, and it got immediately closed.

How?? Why?? Should I use these powers for good, or for evil?

> [Is the "set" of all algebraic extensions a set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792655/is-the-set-of-all-algebraic-extensions-a-set)
>
> [image: Superpowers]

Comment: It was inevitable.

Comment: Fr the universe recognizes my awesome internet powers?

Comment: You were probably bitten by a radioactive spider. Because science.

Comment: @Alex: Impossible. But I was recently chosen as a herald of Galactus. I suppose that would explain this issue.

Comment: Congrats, Asaf, on your new superpowers.

Comment: Best meta thread title ever.  Power overwhelming!

Comment: And... it appears you noticed this [before we moderators were notified](http://moderator.stackexchange.com/2014/05/may-2014-newsletter/#thor).

Comment: You should try it for some evil =)

Comment: May the forth be with you

Comment: @Norbert: May the twenty fourth be with you.

Comment: @WillieWong The link is broken now that the mod newsletter has been moved to http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/ (to free up the URL for Moderators.SE).

Comment: Frightening the first time it happens

Comment: @Henry: Plenty of superhero comics have dealt with the initial shock of having superpowers. It's nothing new! :-)

Comment: Both the poster and the user in the pic ended up becoming moderators haha

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a new feature, users with a gold badge in one of the original tags of the question can close as duplicate with a single vote. The rationale being that a user that answered that many questions in this tag is likely to know very well all the possible duplicate targets. This also goes for reopening, so you are also able to reverse bad duplicate closures in that tag with a single click.

[The answer from Shog on this topic on MSO:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254590/347857)

> Yes, you are now a Superhero, able to wield [the mighty
>   Mjölnir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212).
>
> The rules are:
>
> - You can instantly close *as a duplicate* any question that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
> - You can instantly reopen any question *closed as a duplicate* that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
> - You can only close or reopen a given question *once* (this hasn't changed).
> - If you get in a fight with someone over whether a question should be closed, moderators will be notified and they'll <s>hit everyone with
>     hammers</s> lock everything down and tell you to go home.
>
> Remember: duplicates are questions that *ask for a solution to
>   fundamentally identical problems* - many questions have similar or
>   identical *answers* but are not duplicates. By the same token, many
>   questions are asked using *very* different wordings but seek to solve
>   identical questions - closing these helps folks find their way to a
>   solution even when they don't know what terms to search for.
>
> **GO FORTH AND USE YOUR NEW POWERS FOR GOOD!**

Comment: With great power comes great responsibility -Stan Lee $\tag*{}$ Absolute power corrupts absolutely -John Dalberg-Acton $\tag*{}$ Take your pick

Comment: http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/HowTo:Get_Super_Powers

Comment: @robjohn: I choose the third option: I HAVE THE POWEEEERRRR!!! ~He-Man.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: [See also.](http://daylateanddollarshort.com/bloog/master-of-the-puniverse/) --Me, man!

Comment: @robjohn Glad you left "Kneel before Zod" off the list!

Comment: @rschwieb: I don't think that anyone here is the son of Jor El, so...

Comment: @robjohn So corruption is the ultimate responsibility! Explains the US Congress...

Comment: Moderators do be hitting everyone with hammers though.