# You want me to put the hammer down?

Tags: feature-request, exact-duplicates, migration, dupehammer

I have a small request to make about gold badge hammers for duplicates:

> If a question is migrated from another site, allow the first retag to be included in the tags whose gold members are eligible for [Thor-like powers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13702/why-do-i-have-superpowers).
>
> And if not, then at least those which arrive under [untagged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Comment: This could probably be retagged, *looks at Martin*.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is what you had in mind, but I have created ([meta-tag:dupehammer]) tag and copied [tag-wiki from meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/dupehammer/info).

Comment: Oh, that's useful, thanks! (Now this tag have two questions, both by me, and both include some reference to superheroes in the title...)

Comment: I propose the tag [calling-Martin] for such questions.

Comment: @T.Bongers: I think that posting on meta is essentially [calling-Martin]. :-)

Comment: (By the way, I'd be happy to hear why people think this is not a good feature!)

Answer (score 6):

I do not support this request. Users are intentionally prevented from giving themselves the closing superpower by editing tags. This is done to prevent  abuse of the hammer (which would be rare) and bias in choosing tags for the question (which is more likely). These reasons apply to migrated questions just as to others.

Also, the fruits of implementing this request would not justify added complexity. Since the introduction of dupehammer, there were 18 questions migrated here and closed as a duplicate. Full list is below, but here is the breakdown of what happened.

- Dupehammer applied: **six** questions (4, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12)
- Tags edited, but even if they were there originally, dupehammer would not apply: **five** questions (3, 5, 7, 8, 13)
- Tags edited, and dupehammer would apply if they were there originally: **one** question (18)

---

1. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804775/example-of-function-lebesgue-integrable-but-not-riemann
2. [Parametric Equation of a 3D Helix Tube Surface?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806847/parametric-equation-of-a-3d-helix-tube-surface)
3. [Diophantine equation: $2 a^2 + 2 b^2 = c^2 + d^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814076/diophantine-equation-2-a2-2-b2-c2-d2)
4. [conditional expectation of the Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818410/conditional-expectation-of-the-brownian-motion)
5. [Antipodal map commutes with antipodal map?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818981/antipodal-map-commutes-with-antipodal-map)
6. [deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827108/behaviour-of-the-sum-of-2-kappa-for-all-kappa-lambda-when-lambda-is-si)
7. [Does this Sum converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835311/does-this-sum-converge)
8. [deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835313/does-this-series-converge-or-diverge)
9. [deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837438/proving-some-number-is-algebraic-over-k)
10. [Random 0-1 matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842667/random-0-1-matrices)
11. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846630/help-on-step-of-the-real-numbers-are-uncountable-proof
12. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853544/2-norm-of-a-canonical-jordan-form-and-spectral-radius
13. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854606/finding-out-the-wrong-number-in-the-series
14. [Localization and Direct limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869299/localization-and-direct-limit)
15. [$i^{-1} F$ a sheaf if and only if $\varinjlim_{ U \subseteq X \text{ open}, ~ x,y \in U } F(U) \to F_x \times F_y$ is an isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869300/i-1-f-a-sheaf-if-and-only-if-varinjlim-u-subseteq-x-text-open-x)
16. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870375/probability-question-regarding-arrangements
17. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871939/how-to-estimate-the-covariance-matrix-if-the-unnormalized-pdf-is-known-but-integ
18. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876627/cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-functions-on-r

Comment: I agree that this power can be abused. But I don't see how this can be any different from other Mjolnir abuses. I also think that Mathematica.SE or SO wouldn't have [logic] and [calculus] or [group-theory] tags.

Comment: My point is that of course that general "retag-hammer" opens a huge window for abuse, but I think that in the case of migrated questions, especially those arrived with [untagged] this should be alleviated.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I understood your point, but the reason for dupehammering is to alleviate a problem of *scale*. This is a non-existent problem for migrated questions. Since mid-May, when the hammer was introduced, over $700$ questions were closed as duplicates. Your proposal would affect $1$ (one) question during the same timespan.