# Can one avoid gold badge superpowers by temporarily removing tags?

Tags: support, closing, exact-duplicates, dupehammer

As described [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13702/why-do-i-have-superpowers), earning a gold tag badge has the side effect that one's votes to close questions in the tag as duplicates become immediately binding instead of going through the usual voting process.

Has anybody tried to see if it is possible to suppress those superpowers by *first* editing the question to remove the offending tag, *then* voting to close and finally rolling back the edit?

Or will the superpowers retroactively activate when the question is edited to put the tag back?

Comment: An interesting question, as idle curiosity. Doing this in practice, however,  would be abusive in my opinion.

Comment: I don't really see the point, personally. You should (ideally) only vote to close as duplicate when you're sure that it is one, so there shouldn't be a problem with accelerating the process (note that the closure is not binding, it can be overturned by the usual process).

Comment: Gold badges give you to ability to command "sea creatures". Changing tags takes the sea creatures out of the water, but it doesn't make them stop being sea creatures. Even out of the water. Just look at Zoidberg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

404's answer is apparently not true anymore -- [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702197/could-we-invent-a-number-h-such-that-h-1-over0-similarly-to-the-w) had the [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) tag (for which I have the hammer) originally. I edited it to remove it, and then voted to close as a duplicate; the vote was not binding.

Out of curiosity, I tried to reinsert [logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic), which didn't retroactively make my close vote binding, so the hustle described in the question seems to work now.

Answer (score 18):

The behavior was [changed in October 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308573).  At present, having a gold badge in a *current* tag of the question results in instant closing.

To prevent abuse, the above does not apply if the user added that tag or approved an edit adding it.

Comment: Well, dammit...